# Ошибка при сборке Vue.js проекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack4, vue-cli

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста пытаюсь собрать vue.js проект и при сборке выдаёт ошибку, откатывал проект до предыдущего состояния когда отсутствовала ошибка но при повторной сборки на всёравно показывалась.
Подскажите изачего она появляется и как её исправить, зарания спасибо.
[image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: Смотрите причину в файле `*-debug.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что что-то с npm-модулем. Удали node_modules и заново накати `npm i`